# Fonts similar to Muller Bold

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, web-fonts

I am currently creating display Ads. We have been using Muller Bold for some of our other branding but I cannot use that font for the display Ads as Google fonts does not offer it. Does anybody know of a similar font that I could use?

Thanks

Comment: Please include a screenshot or at the very least a link to where we can see this typeface. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Montserrat Bold](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Montserrat) is quite similar:
[image]